# how to format value for xml object class

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML. I have converted this to class file so i can pass the value into xml objects for this node. But i have stuck on one point for pass the value for this objects that is below. Can you describe me how can i write the code for the same. Last of the question i have provide my code

```
<m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' >
```

Below is an xml

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' > 
  <SOAP:Body UserGUID = '{redacted}' > 
    <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m = 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' > 
         <Order UserID = '1' Notes = 'Pick CVS Lenexa.' CustomerID = '3' > 
 </Order >  
 </m:SaveOrder > 
 </SOAP:Body >
 </SOAP:Envelope>
```

And the class that is created for the xml is below.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Order")]
    public class Order {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UserID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="CustomerID")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="SaveOrder", Namespace="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/")]
    public class SaveOrder {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Order")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="m", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string M { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="SaveOrder", Namespace="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/")]
        public SaveOrder SaveOrder { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UserGUID")]
        public string UserGUID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="SOAP", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAP { get; set; }
    }
```

Code where i have stuck

```
var SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Envelope
           {
             Body = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Body
               {
                 UserGUID = guid,
                 SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.SaveOrder
                 {

                 }

               }
            };
```

Comment: I can't quite tell, but I think you are [asking how to deserialize XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8). I can tell you that you cannot mark every node as a root if you are going to use `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: crowcoder thanks for your comments problem is with  `<m:SaveOrder` how i code for this part

Comment: Problem with 'm'

Comment: You are not showing the code that is giving an error. You can edit the question to include your full exception detail and the code that is throwing the error. If that is your exact XML, and not a copy/paste issue then you have to remove the spaces in the attributes.

Comment: m is not an attributes it is a new namespace like SOAP on the first line of the Xml.